# Traduction de "I have a hard time imagining him doing that"

Tags: traduction

> A: Pierre will start working at the restaurant this summer. He will be washing the dishes.
>
> B: That’s unbelievable! I have a hard time imagining him doing that.

Quelle est une bonne traduction de la dernière partie ?

> A: Pierre va commencer à travailler au restaurant cet été. Il va faire la vaiselle.
>
> B: C’est incroyable ! J’ai du mal à _____

Je doute qu’on puisse dire *J’ai du mal à l’imaginer faire ça*.

Comment: In an informal context, you can definitely say "J'ai du mal à l'imaginer faire ça", or "J'ai du mal à m'imaginer ça". "Imaginer quelqu'un faire quelque chose" is completely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Avoir du mal à* est habituellement suivi de l'infinitif, que la difficulté soit matérielle ou psychologique.

- > J'ai du mal à ouvrir cette bouteille d'une seule main.
- > J'ai du mal à l'imaginer faire ça.

*Imaginer* peut être suivi de l'infinitif, d'un gérondif ou d'une proposition introduite par *que*.

> J'ai du mal à l'imaginer faire ça.

→ c'est la construction la plus courante.

> J'ai du mal à l'imaginer faisant ça.

→ se rencontre mais beaucoup moins que l'infinitif

> J'ai du mal à imaginer qu'il puisse faire ça / qu'il fasse ça.

→ à noter dans cette construction l'emploi du subjonctif dans la subordonnée (fait hypothétique), et le complément de *imaginer* est devenu le sujet du verbe.

Answer (score 3):

While the infinitive « l’imaginer *faire* ça » construction is not deemed
strictly incorrect, it would be more usual to use the « que » subordinate clause with the subjunctive mood:

> Je ne peux pas imaginer qu'il fasse ça.

Or if you want to keep the infinitive structure:

> Je le vois mal faire ça.

Comment: puisque c'est dans un dialogue, on peut s'autoriser quelques libertés, me semble-t-il.

Answer (score 1):

> J'ai du mal à l'imaginer faire ça.

Est tout à fait correct. Les seuls problèmes que cela peut poser sont:

- L'usage de multiples pronoms ("l'", "ça"), qui peut embrouiller le lecteur, mais la version anglaise les comporte aussi.
- L'usage de "ça" qui doit être remplacé par "cela" si on est en registre soutenu. Ce n'est a priori pas le cas ici.

En tous cas c'est une formulation que vous pouvez entendre au cours d'une conversation, votre traduction est très bonne.